# CTE values need to insert into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below query i am not able to insert common table expression select values into another table.

```sql
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        rd.reorderhistoryId,
        rd.dateCreated,
        rd.personId,
        rd.reorderId,
        rd.statusNo,
        rd.createdBy,
        r.OrganizationId
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             MIN(reorderhistoryId) AS reorderhistoryId,
             MIN(personId) AS personId,
             reorderId
         FROM 
             reorderHistoryDetails
         GROUP BY 
             reorderId) rh 
    INNER JOIN 
        reorderHistoryDetails rd ON rd.reorderhistoryId = rh.reorderhistoryId
    INNER JOIN 
        reorderDetails r ON r.personId = rd.personId
    WHERE 
        rd.statusNo = 1059
)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5
    rlst.personId AS personId,
    'Start Reorder Process' AS reorderStatusType,
    1 AS productId,
    3 AS amountPaid,
    rlst.reorderId,
    rlst.OrganizationId AS orgId,
    rlst.createdBy,
    rlst.dateCreated,
    rlst.dateCreated AS timeStamp
FROM
    cte rlst
INNER JOIN 
    doctororderall d ON rlst.personId = d.personId
                     AND d.productId = 1
                     AND YEAR(rlst.dateCreated) = YEAR(d.dateCreated)
INNER JOIN 
    patientdetails pd ON pd.personId = d.personId
WHERE 
    rlst.datecreated > '2020-09-01'
    AND rlst.dateCreated <= '2021-10-06'

INSERT INTO rouletteTracking (personId, reorderStatusType, productId,
                              amountPaid, reorderId, orgId, 
                              createdBy, dateCreated, timeStamp)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
> Invalid object name 'cte'.

Comment: 1. White space and line breaks are "magical" things; that made that unreadable blob of code you had readable. 2. Semi Colons (`;`) are statement **terminators** they go at the end of *all* your statements, not the start of statements that require the ***previous*** statement to be properly terminated. 3. As the name (Common Table **Expression**) suggests, a CTE is an expression; if it isn't defined in the statement it doesn't exist in the scope of the statement. The CTE isn't defined in your second statement so it doesn't exist.

Comment: sir what is the solution please. @Larnu

Comment: What I imply; define the CTE in the statement. Or, alternatively, insert the data into a (temporary) table, and then `SELECT` and `INSERT` from that.

Comment: sir CTE data is not empty, which statement please can give me the line where i have to modify please. @Larnu

Comment: I didn't say the CTE was empty, I said it wasn't defined. The CTE clearly doesn't result in an empty result, as your first query returns 5 rows. The problem is you try to reference that CTE in a statement later, but as I mentioned, you haven't defined that CTE (again) so you get an error. As both myself, and Grant in their answer, has stated, the hint is in the name: Common Table **Expression**.

Comment: where i have to define sir can you please share the line or code. @Larnu

Comment: BTW,please don't assume people's genders here; calling everyone "sir" suggests you are assuming everyone is male. You agreed to the code of conduct when you signed up to the site, and that means using gender neutral language unless asked otherwise. You could easily end up offending someone by assuming the wrong gender.

Comment: apologies can please update your answer with some query. @Larnu

Comment: @MazharKhan I highly recommend getting comfortable reading documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 This is all said explicitly there. If you avoid documentation you'll have to come to SO for every little thing that comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name Common Table Expression is a bit misleading. Many people read it and see the word "TABLE" very prominently. They then assume that they're dealing with a new kind of temporary table or table variable. However, the word to focus on is "EXPRESSION".

A CTE is only useable within the statement that defines it. It's not, in any way, temporary storage. It's simply a query. It's like having a sub-query to define a table like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable) as NotaCTEButActsLikeOne
```

In order to do your process, you need to move the entire SELECT statement including your CTE into a single statement with the INSERT process.

EDIT:

Here. You just move everything so that it's a single statement:

```
WITH
cte AS
    (SELECT rd.reorderhistoryId,
            rd.dateCreated,
            rd.personId,
            rd.reorderId,
            rd.statusNo,
            rd.createdBy,
            r.OrganizationId
     FROM (SELECT MIN(reorderhistoryId) AS reorderhistoryId,
                  MIN(personId) AS personId,
                  reorderId
           FROM reorderHistoryDetails
           GROUP BY reorderId) rh --on d.personId=rh.personId
          INNER JOIN reorderHistoryDetails rd ON rd.reorderhistoryId = rh.reorderhistoryId
          INNER JOIN reorderDetails r ON r.personId = rd.personId
     WHERE rd.statusNo = 1059)
INSERT INTO rouletteTracking (personId,
                              reorderStatusType,
                              productId,
                              amountPaid,
                              reorderId,
                              orgId,
                              createdBy,
                              dateCreated,
                              timeStamp)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5
       rlst.personId AS personId,
       'Start Reorder Process' AS reorderStatusType,
       1 AS productId,
       3 AS amountPaid,
       rlst.reorderId,
       rlst.OrganizationId AS orgId,
       rlst.createdBy,
       rlst.dateCreated,
       rlst.dateCreated AS timeStamp
FROM cte rlst
     INNER JOIN doctororderall d ON rlst.personId = d.personId
                                AND d.productId = 1
                                AND YEAR(rlst.dateCreated) = YEAR(d.dateCreated)
     INNER JOIN patientdetails pd ON pd.personId = d.personId
--inner join (select min(reorderhistoryId) as reorderhistoryId,min(personId) as personId,reorderId from reorderHistoryDetails where statusNo=1059 and personId=226020  group by reorderId )as  rh  on d.personId=rh.personId
--inner join reorderHistoryDetails rd on rd.reorderHistoryId=rh.reorderhistoryId and rd.statusNo=1059 
WHERE rlst.datecreated > '2020-09-01'
  AND rlst.dateCreated <= '2021-10-06';
```

Also, please, the semi-colon is a statement terminator, not something you put in front of the WITH clause. Examples on line do that so that people can copy the code and it will compile (a righteous approach). However, just putting it at the end of your statements, everything will work and the code won't look awful.

Comment: can you write full answer getting confused sir. @Grant Fritchey

Comment: *"Examples on line do that so that people can copy the code and it will compile"* In my opinion, if you copy and paste CTE examples and it doesn't compile (due to a lack of statement terminating) that's not the example's fault but the person who copied it and didn't properly write their prior SQL correctly. Online examples without a "beginningator" compile fine if the person copying it wrote their own SQL correctly. ;) it's not the online example's fault for syntax errors in someone else's code.

Comment: I don't do it that way. I have friends who do. I respect their reasons, even if I don't completely agree with them. Let's face it, if you're copying & pasting online solutions without understanding how they work and testing them in your systems to get them right, you're calling down everything that happens after that.

Answer (score 1):

Both myself (in the comments) and Grant (in their answer) has already covered this, however, to repeat this a Common Table **Expression** is an **expression**. It's scope is limited to the scope of the statement it is define in (like other expressions). If you properly terminate your statements you'll see you have **two** statements above; a `SELECT` and an `INSERT`, and thus the CTE isn't defined in the second:

```sql
WITH cte AS
    (SELECT rd.reorderhistoryId,
            rd.dateCreated,
            rd.personId,
            rd.reorderId,
            rd.statusNo,
            rd.createdBy,
            r.OrganizationId
     FROM (SELECT MIN(reorderhistoryId) AS reorderhistoryId,
                  MIN(personId) AS personId,
                  reorderId
           FROM reorderHistoryDetails
           GROUP BY reorderId) rh --on d.personId=rh.personId
          INNER JOIN reorderHistoryDetails rd ON rd.reorderhistoryId = rh.reorderhistoryId
          INNER JOIN reorderDetails r ON r.personId = rd.personId
     WHERE rd.statusNo = 1059)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5
       rlst.personId AS personId,
       'Start Reorder Process' AS reorderStatusType,
       1 AS productId,
       3 AS amountPaid,
       rlst.reorderId,
       rlst.OrganizationId AS orgId,
       rlst.createdBy,
       rlst.dateCreated,
       rlst.dateCreated AS timeStamp
FROM cte rlst
     INNER JOIN doctororderall d ON rlst.personId = d.personId
                                AND d.productId = 1
                                AND YEAR(rlst.dateCreated) = YEAR(d.dateCreated)
     INNER JOIN patientdetails pd ON pd.personId = d.personId
WHERE rlst.datecreated > '2020-09-01'
  AND rlst.dateCreated <= '2021-10-06'; --This statement ends HERE

--New statement starts here. The CTE cte has no context here.
INSERT INTO rouletteTracking (personId,
                              reorderStatusType,
                              productId,
                              amountPaid,
                              reorderId,
                              orgId,
                              createdBy,
                              dateCreated,
                              timeStamp)
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

*Assuming* you want to `SELECT` the `TOP (5)` (arbitrary) rows first from the CTE first, and then `INSERT` the entire result set from the CTE into your table afterwards, I would `INSERT` the data into a temporary table first, and then `SELECT` and `INSERT` from that:

```sql
WITH cte AS
    (SELECT rd.reorderhistoryId,
            rd.dateCreated,
            rd.personId,
            rd.reorderId,
            rd.statusNo,
            rd.createdBy,
            r.OrganizationId
     FROM (SELECT MIN(reorderhistoryId) AS reorderhistoryId,
                  MIN(personId) AS personId,
                  reorderId
           FROM reorderHistoryDetails
           GROUP BY reorderId) rh --on d.personId=rh.personId
          INNER JOIN reorderHistoryDetails rd ON rd.reorderhistoryId = rh.reorderhistoryId
          INNER JOIN reorderDetails r ON r.personId = rd.personId
     WHERE rd.statusNo = 1059)
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM cte;

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5
       rlst.personId AS personId,
       'Start Reorder Process' AS reorderStatusType,
       1 AS productId,
       3 AS amountPaid,
       rlst.reorderId,
       rlst.OrganizationId AS orgId,
       rlst.createdBy,
       rlst.dateCreated,
       rlst.dateCreated AS timeStamp
FROM #Temp rlst
     INNER JOIN doctororderall d ON rlst.personId = d.personId
                                AND d.productId = 1
                                AND YEAR(rlst.dateCreated) = YEAR(d.dateCreated)
     INNER JOIN patientdetails pd ON pd.personId = d.personId
WHERE rlst.datecreated > '2020-09-01'
  AND rlst.dateCreated <= '2021-10-06'
ORDER BY {The Column to order by}; --This statement ends HERE

--New statement starts here. The CTE cte has no context here.
INSERT INTO rouletteTracking (personId,
                              reorderStatusType,
                              productId,
                              amountPaid,
                              reorderId,
                              orgId,
                              createdBy,
                              dateCreated,
                              timeStamp)
SELECT *
FROM #Temp;
```

*Note: I expect the `INSERT` statement at the end to still fail. You attempt to insert into a `timestamp` column (a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`); that isn't allowed.*

Comment: thanks for your effort for me getting this error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#Temp'. @Larnu

Comment: Oops, that should be `SELECT ... INTO` not `INSERT INTO...SELECT`.